# How can I locate the user which is using specific app in android ?

Tags: android

I am making a app in android. Now I want know following things.

How can a server know in specific area how much user are using this application? Example server want to know how many user are using this app in london city or any part of a london city. Here the problem is user can be on any location so its location is not permanent but when he connected to server through android app I want that in specific area how many users are online through this app and I want to send messages to them.

Is it possible in android ?

Comment: You can fetch the user's location each time user uses your application and send that location to server. This way you can know the location of each application. This requires webservice, Internet Permission. For unique entry of each device you require IMEI

Comment: bur if user continuously moving and his app connected to the enternet then what i do? if i update user location after a specifc time interval then what kind of overhed can be on network?

Comment: Battery will finish very soon. You need a periodic update like every minute or every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. how can a server now in specific area how much user are using this application?

I'll have to separate that to two different things:

- about knowing the are:   the only way your server could know anything about the running app location is that your application would send it this information. Therefore - your app should retrieve the user location based GPS /WIFI and send it to the server.   best way would be using [Google play services fused location provider](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html), which can bring you the user location in the accuracy relevant to you with minimal battery impact
- "using the application" - please define what exactly your definition for "using the application"  it's not that simple as it sounds.

> I want that in specific area how many users are online through this app and I want to send messages to them.

Again, I don't understand what's "online" mean exactly in android terms.

Anyway, there is no Android API provides directly sending GCM push messages to different "location groups". I wish there was such. You'll have to manage such feature yourself by implement the logic that decide based on the locations been sent from your app (from a specific user) to your server.

Comment: online means app connected to the enternet

Comment: in that case my app continuously giving updates to server so what kind of overhead on the netwrok? and what is the status of my battery?

Comment: @user2777354:  if you'll use location services for requesting location updates every 20-30 minutes with "city accuracy" then the impact on battery would be very low from that, but there is indeed the issue of openning the network radio for sending that location to the server - opening WIFI / 3G Radio frequently can potentially drain battery very fast, but as long as you do it once an hour or two - I don't see any problem with that.  also you can betch (save pesistently on sqlite database) the locations you retreive and  sending it all tougether one an hour or two

Comment: no in my case user always connected to the enternet during travel

Comment: @user2777354: I advise you to see the following videos/ post:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUemfrKe65c    https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/index.html      https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bte_GHuxUGc

Comment: @user2777354: connected to the internet !=  3G / WIFI radio is in full active state for transmition.     3G radio is active when there is currently network requests been executed, and some short time afterwards

Answer (score 0):

To find out how many users are (roughly) in an area, you can use Google Analytics, but you cannot send messages to them.
If you want to get a more precise location and send messages to the users, you need an own server, for example one at Google App Engine, where your app uses GPS or Network to locate the user and uploads the position to the server continuously. Then you could write a server application which allows you to see where the users are and write them messages via Google Cloud Messaging or email or whatever you want.

Comment: now through your solution will my location continuously send to server? suppose iam travelling and my app is connected to enternet and app sending my location continuosly to server but in this case after how many time interval my app send location to server  can i specify the time interval ?and what kind of overhed on netwrok?

Comment: Yes, of course you can define the time interval. With a short time interval, your app would definitely use more data and battery. You could also only send the position when your users are on WiFi, when the usage while they're travelling doesn't interest you.

Comment: the major issue is that my user is travelling continuosly

Comment: Then you have to use quite a short interval.

Comment: the major issue is that app user is travelling continuosly in that case how can i save my battery through efficient way so that  app send user location to server and battery also save.

Comment: As Tal Kanel said, when you want to send the position to the server very often, the battery impact will be too large. The only way is to send it with a larger interval or batch multiple locations. But that wouldn't help when you want to send the user a message because the server only knows the location from the last batch.